# Change text at the top bar of sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to find where I can change (override) the default titles appearing on the top bar of sonata admin.

[image]

For example, in this page (list of users), I want to change "Users" to "List of all users"

I found where to change the title "Sonata Project" and the default Icon :

```
sonata_admin:
    .....
    title:      %sonata_admin.title%
    title_logo: %sonata_admin.logo_title%
    .....
```

But I didn't find where to change the particular title of each page !

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's a translation key in this format:

```
breadcrumb.link_user_list
```

Defined [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/3.x/Resources/translations/SonataUserBundle.en.xliff#L25). So [adding your own translation key](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#translations) in a file at a higher scope in your application will override it. Domain is `SonataUserBundle` and locale is obviously `en`.

Comment: That's right! Also I want to add that there is also `breadcrumb.link_user_delete`, which should also be translated. The part `user` in the key is the name of the model entity. If you want to create translations for the entities in your bundle, let's say AppBundle, it can be done in a file `AppBundle.en.yml` placed in `src/AppBundle/Resources/translations`.

Comment: The name of the bundle, for example `AppBundle` should be set as value of `setTranslationDomain` in the admin service.